# How do I represent transformations between two shapes on a card in an OOP system?

Tags: python, oop, object

I am attempting to expand on an OOP design I have already created.  Here is an example of the intelligence test: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcsuDhIx8hU

[image]

I have two (or more) cards.  Each card has two or more shapes on them.  Each shape is related to another shape on the same card e.g. one shape may be 'inside' another shape or 'above' etc.  I can create a class for 'card' that is composed of two objects, each of class type 'shape'.

I have two questions:

1. Each shape on a card is related to another, e.g. shape a is 'above' 
   or 'inside' shape b etc.  What would be the best way to represent this relationship?
2. This is the more difficult question.  If I have two cards, each shape on one card can be a transformation of a shape on another card.  e.g. shape a on card 2 may be shape a on card 1 'shrunk', 'reflected' or 'rotated'.  How can I represent this transformation?

I started out with a card array each containing a single object (a shape).  I then had another object of type 'relationship' that contained two shapes and stored a transformation between each.

Comment: What are these cards used for? How is the relationship between the shapes important to the use case?

Comment: Technically and mathematically, this transformation is called a "similarity transform." The shapes are related by a matrix which describes the uniform scaling, rotation, mirroring, and translation of the other shape. You can also find this in computer vision and computer graphics literature. There's some good info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation. So the mathematical way to represent this for arbitrary shapes is to define the shape by their points, in which case you can estimate what similarity transform relates two sets of points. This is not trivial, though.

Comment: Other options are to describe the rotation by an angle around the center of the shape to a particular vertex (the first vertex, say), the scale by some factor (the distance from the center to a particular vertex), a translation of the center of the shape to the origin, and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will look into those.  What I am really looking for at this point though is how to do the OOP design.  I want to know which things should be classes and how objects in those classes will be related (e.g. composition etc).

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just add attributes to each card that can fetch the shape attributes from the other cards.

For example, you can have a self.shape field that for each specific shape and when you want to change the shape of a card you call that method on the respective card.

Comment: I don't want to change the shape, I want to have two different cards and have a representation of the transformations and relationships between those cards.  There may even be multiple transformations represented (e.g. rotated and shrunk).